# Find source of ajax call to example.com/undefined

Tags: ajax, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, developer-tools

My WordPress installation has mysteriously begun to stop applying some layout fixes and I suspect that it has something to do with a strange GET request that I'm trying to hunt down:

[image]

I'm guessing that I'm assembling the url, `mydomain.com/undefined` with a variable that I fail to assign a value and is thus evaluated as "undefined". My question is, where is this happening.

When I click the link to "undefined:1" on the right, it takes me to a list of images and displays the markup for my site's 404 page:

[image]

How can I isolate the place on my site where the GET request is being made?

Answer (score 0):

Try [XHR breakpoints](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints#xhr). After defining the breakpoint, you should pause on the JS that's making the request. If it happens during load, then reload the page, and you should still pause when that code is encountered.

[image: XHR breakpoint]